# How to make Folding@Home run when idle?

Tags: ubuntu

I've installed and configured Folding@Home:

```
$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
$ FAHClient --version
7.5.1
$ cat /etc/fahclient/config.xml 
<config>
  <!-- Network -->
  <proxy v=':8080'/>

  <!-- Slot Control -->
  <idle v='true'/>
  <power v='FULL'/>

  <!-- User Information -->
  <team v='[omitted]'/>
  <user v='[omitted]'/>

  <!-- Folding Slots -->
  <slot id='0' type='CPU'/>
  <slot id='1' type='GPU'/>
</config>
```

However, after starting the service never starts processing. If I toggle the [client's `idle` setting](https://client.foldingathome.org/) it starts processing immediately, but then the machine is pretty much unusable for anything else, even if I reduce the `power` setting to medium. **How can I make sure Folding@Home does work when, and only when, the machine is idle?** That is, with no manual intervention it should start processing after a few minutes of idle time, and should immediately stop processing when no longer idle.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and still have it after upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04 and FAHClient to 7.6.13. This is quite frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem and the client never thinks my computer is idle. I ended up making a script that only resumes FAH when the screen is locked. It worked wonderfully. You can check here:

https://github.com/Madoshakalaka/gnome-folding-at-screenlock

Here are the full steps to get this working in case the repo goes down:

1. Copy this service file to `/home/YOUR_DESTOP_USER/.config/systemd/user/gnome-folding-at-screenlock.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=FAH controller based on screen locking/unlocking signals

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gnome-folding-at-screenlock.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

2. Copy this shell script to your `/usr/bin/gnome-folding-at-screenlock.sh` and give it
   the executable permission with `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gnome-folding-at-screenlock.sh`.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
# Somehow I receive duplicate signals during locking and unlocking.
# It's a weird behavior but does no harm in our case.
  while read x; do
    case "$x" in
    "boolean true")
      echo "screen turns locked. Initiate folding" && FAHClient --send-unpause ;;
    "boolean false") echo "screen turns unlocked. Unfold! Unfold!" && FAHClient --send-pause ;;
    *) ;;
    esac
  done
```

3. `sudo systemctl enable foldingathome && sudo systemctl start foldingathome` If you haven't already done so.
   Note our script won't start or stop the `foldingathome` service.
   It assumes the service is started and pauses/unpauses folding via `FAHClient`.
   The pause or unpause will be persisted in the configuration file located at `/etc/foldingathome/config.xml`.
4. Go to the dashboard in your browser at `http://localhost:7396/` and change some options. You should tick the
   "While I'm working" option because we are not relying on FAH's idle detection anymore.
   Also, you can set up your ideal power level too. Finally, stop the folding by hitting the "Stop Folding" button,
   which actually adds a `<paused v='true'>` tag to your config file (It does exactly the same thing our script does when you wake up your monitor).
5. `systemctl --user enable gnome-folding-at-screenlock.service`. Do not run as root or with sudo because locking and unlocking is tied to your desktop user.
6. `systemctl --user start gnome-folding-at-screenlock.service`. Do not run as root or with sudo.
7. Done! Now you can just hit <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> and lock the screen whenever you will be away from the computer.
   Proteins will start folding right away! When you are back, unlock your computer,
   and the folding will pause immediately!
8. For bonus points, go to GNOME's `Settings > Power` and turn off automatic suspension, otherwise no extended folding
   will be possible. By default, suspension happens after 20 minutes of inactivity, this will stop FAH too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quick-and-dirty solution, inspired by the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259963.

```
#!/bin/bash

let TIMEOUT_MINUTES=5
let TIMEOUT_MS=TIMEOUT_MINUTES*60000

while [ 0 ]
do
IDLE=$(xprintidle)
    if [ $IDLE -lt $TIMEOUT_MS ]
        then
            FAHClient --send-pause
        else
            FAHClient --send-unpause
    fi
    sleep 15
done
```

Just change the `TIMEOUT_MINUTES` and `sleep` values to your liking and then set up it up to start at login.

If `xprintidle` isn't in your repo, as was my case in running Fedora 37, you can build it from source (available at https://github.com/g0hl1n/xprintidle).